# How to add icon/image along with popup menu in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Below is my code.

```
var choices = ['Settings', 'Log Out'];
void choiceAction(String choice){
  print(choice);
}

  Widget aapBarSection(String title, Color color, BuildContext context){
    return AppBar(
      title: Text(title, style:TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Poppins-Regular'), ),
      centerTitle: true,
      backgroundColor: color,
      actions: [
        PopupMenuButton<String>(
          onSelected: choiceAction,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context){
            return choices.map((String choice) {
              return PopupMenuItem<String>(
                value: choice,
                child: Text(choice),
              );
            }).toList();
          },
        )
      ],
      leading: IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
        onPressed: (){
          exit(0);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

menu items are showing but how to show **image/icon** as per the items like for settings(**settings icon**) and for logout(**logout icon**) with it?
Can anybody help me please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ListTile` as child or `Row`.

```
PopupMenuItem<String>(
                value: choice,
                child: ListTile(
                  leading: Icon(Icons.work), // your icon
                  title: Text(choice),
                ),
              )
```

Comment: Thanks! @John Joe, but I want to show two different icons as per the different text. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
var choices = [
    {'title': 'Home', 'icon': const Icon(Icons.home)},
    {'title': 'Profile', 'icon': const Icon(Icons.people)},
    {'title': 'Logout', 'icon': const Icon(Icons.logout)}
];

var actions = [
    PopupMenuButton<String>(
        onSelected: choiceAction,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctx) {
            return choices.map((ch) {
            return PopupMenuItem<String>(
            value: ch['title'].toString(),
            child: ListTile(
            leading: ch['icon'] as Widget,
            title: Text(ch['title'].toString())));
        }).toList();
    })
];
void choiceAction(String choice){
    print(choice);
}

class _HomeVendorPageState extends State<HomeVendorPage> {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
                title: Text(widget.title),
                actions: actions,
            ),
            body: Center(
            child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: const [])));
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).